# Export list of app insight names and InstrumentationKey

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

I need to export a list of Application Insights with two columns: Name and Instrumentation Key.

With the following command I get the names, but the column InstrumentationKey is always null.

```
az resource list --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" --query "[].{Name:name, InstrumentationKey:properties.InstrumentationKey}"
```

Without filtering the columns, by running simply

```
az resource list --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components"
```

I can't find the Instrumentation Key.

What is the command to get the Instrumentation Key and relative name for all the resources in a subscription?

Comment: Because, there is no `InstrumentationKey` property in Microsoft.Insights/components command output.

Comment: Where can I find this field other than the Essentials tab of the resource page in azure portal?

Comment: You can find it on Application insights app and there click on overview https://i.imgur.com/ZiQk9vy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get the expected results using `az monitor app-insights component show`. Below is complete Query that worked for me.

```
$a = az monitor app-insights component show | ConvertFrom-Json
$a | Select-Object name,instrumentationKey
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]